# In Kotlin: What is an elegant way to sum two values of a common key from two maps?

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin

I have an existing map that holds simple integer values. I'd like to update that existing map by the value of a given map that holds *one of* the possible keys.

```
val originMap = mutableMapOf("Foo" to 10, "Bar" to 5)
val additionalMap = mapOf("Foo" to 4)

// questioned logic

assertThat(originMap).containsEntry("Foo", 14)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
val mergedMap = (originMap.toList() + additionalMap.toList())
        .groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
        .map { (key, values) -> key to values.sum() }
        .toMap()

println(mergedMap) // [(Foo, 14), (Bar, 5)]
```

[Try it here!](https://pl.kotl.in/3ebbtHjVZ)

Comment: That looks good but isn't this possible by some convenience function like `putAll()` instead of it's replacing concept

Comment: @xetra11 The Kotlin stdlib does not offer that as far as I know. :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `originMap` in-place rather than declaring a new `Map`, you can merge `addtionalMap` into it via a side-effect of `forEach`:

```
additionalMap.forEach { (k, v) -> originMap.merge(k, v, Int::plus) }
// Prints {Foo=14, Bar=5}
```

This will take every key (`k`) and value (`v`) from `additionalMap` and add it to the value in `originMap` using `Int::plus`.

Comment: Also thought about it. `merge` is from the Java API though which limits the code to the JVM (which might be ok).

Comment: Yeah, that's fair.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64307217/13968673), but without JVM specific API:

```kotlin
additionalMap.forEach { (k, v) -> originMap[k] = (originMap[k] ?: 0) + v }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution has a minor bug that it will add all additional keys in the `additionalMap` which are not exists in the `originalMap` to the result.
Meaning below will produce output like this:

```
val originMap = mutableMapOf("Foo" to 10, "Bar" to 5)
val additionalMap = mapOf("Foo" to 4, "Baz" to 3)
additionalMap.forEach { (k, v) -> if (originMap.containsKey(k)) originMap.merge(k, v, Int::plus) }
// Prints {Foo=14, Bar=5, Baz=3}
```

So same solution without the minor bug would be like below:

```
additionalMap.forEach { (k, v) -> if (originMap.containsKey(k)) originMap.merge(k, v, Int::plus) }
// Prints {Foo=14, Bar=5}
```

If worried about JVM specific API: then same would be like

```
additionalMap.forEach { (k, v) -> if (originMap[k] != null) originMap[k] = (originMap[k] ?: 0) + v }
// Prints {Foo=14, Bar=5}
```